# IE not loading jquery in $(window).load after window.location.reload();

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

Having a strange issue with IE.

I have code like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('.deleteButton').click(function(){
            var uid = $(this).attr('rel');
        deleteItem(uid);
    });

});
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome,  my function for deleteItem call a $.post and on completion refreshes the page so that it can update the content.

```
$.post("../jphp/deleteOption.php", {id: uid}, function() {window.location.reload(); })
```

However after the page has been reloaded the delete buttons are no longer clickable.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to bind your click on document ready?

Comment: The documentation says that location.reload by default loads from cache and to force overwrite it, you have to use location.reload(forceGet) or you can do location.href = location.href instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
window.location.reload(true); //dont load from cache
```

Comment: I found a solution which was:

 $('.deleteButton').live('click', function(){
        var uid = $(this).attr('rel');
        deleteItem(uid);
    })

Which worked perfectly.  Unfortunately my code has changed since this question, but i will definitely try your solution in future.  Thanks for your response.